# multiply chars by numbers in string

Tags: java

I would like multiply letter by number in a `String` and return other `String`.
I don't know how to concat it when number is higher than 9 and then multiply 
eg.

`String ="a2b10"` convert to `String ="aabbbbbbbbbb"`

string can have different values: `"a2b15"`, `"a16b4c1"`,`"a11b14c5"`

below I made it only for one letter and one number eg. `a1b8`, `a4b7v3`

```
import javafx.util.converter.CharacterStringConverter;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String txt = "a3b2";
    char ch;

    for (int i = 0; i < txt.length(); i++) {
        ch = txt.charAt(i);

        if (((ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'))) {

        } else if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')

        {

            int count = Character.getNumericValue(ch);
            for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                System.out.print(txt.charAt(i - 1));

            }

        } else
            System.out.println("not a letter");

    }
}

}
```

Comment: How does your code relate to your question?  Does your code *work*?  If it doesn't, what do you believe is happening and where is it going wrong?

Comment: my code can convert only  one letter one number, I need one letter two numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it's easier to use regex and group-matching to extract the letter and the number that's following it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String txt = "a3b10";
    String patt = "([a-z])([0-9]*)"; // ([a-z]) will be the first group and ([0-9]*) will be the second

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patt);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(txt);

    while(matcher.find()) {
        String letter = matcher.group(1);
        String number =  matcher.group(2);
        int num = Integer.valueOf(number);
        while (num > 0) {
            System.out.print(letter);
            num--;
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
aaabbbbbbbbbb
```

Comment: Nice simplified and efficient code and really solves the problem. `+1` for that.

Answer (score 0):

When you're looking for numbers and you find one, keep looking for numbers until you find a letter or the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this ...

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String txt = "a10b10";
    char ch;
    char tempChar = ' ';
    int temp = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < txt.length(); i++) {
        ch = txt.charAt(i);

        if (((ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'))) {
            temp = -1;
            tempChar = ch;
        } else if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {

            int count = Character.getNumericValue(ch);

            if (temp != -1) {
                count = ((10*temp) - temp);
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                //System.out.print(txt.charAt(i - 1));
                System.out.print(tempChar);

            }
            temp = count;

        } else {
            System.out.println("not a letter");
        }

    }

}

}
```